# Raising Rotation Matrix to a Power

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

For the general $\sin$ and $\cos$ rotation matrix, $R$, am I right to assume that for a given angle of rotation $\theta$, $R^n$ gives us the rotation matrix for the new angle $nθ$?

In my question I have been given the angle $\pi/53$, and then am asked to work out $R^{2014}$. I have then noted that $2014 \times \pi/53 = 38\pi$. A point rotated by $38π$ is the same as a point rotated by $0π$, and hence I have got $R^{2014}$ is equal to the identity matrix in the case of an angle of $\pi/53$. Is this correct? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yup. You might want to formally prove  that given to rotation matrices $R(\theta)$ and $R(\varphi)$ corresponding to different angles that $R(\theta)R(\varphi) = R(\theta + \varphi)$ and use formal induction but your intuition is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. Try yourself to prove that (as "Squid" suggested), in general:
$$
\left( \begin{array}[cc] 
\,\cos(\alpha) & -\sin(\alpha) \\
\sin(\alpha) & \cos(\alpha)\end{array}\right)\left( \begin{array}[cc] 
\,\cos(\beta) & -\sin(\beta) \\
\sin(\beta) & \cos(\beta)\end{array}\right) = \left( \begin{array}[cc] 
\,\cos(\alpha+\beta) & -\sin(\alpha+\beta) \\
\sin(\alpha+\beta) & \cos(\alpha+\beta)\end{array}\right)
$$

Hint: the trigonometric formulae for the sums of angles may be useful.