# A problem on square matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Problem:if the matrix $A$ is given as-
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix}
   \cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta)\\
  -\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
Then prove that- (where $n$ is a Natural number)
$$ A^n = \begin{pmatrix}
   \cos(n\theta) & \sin(n\theta)\\
  -\sin(n\theta) & \cos(n\theta)\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

---

Since it is given that $n$ is natural number so I have already solved this by using *Mathematical induction* so I dont need any help In induction as I have myself done it ...but I was looking for a better and shorter proof...which I have been unable to find.

Moreover I have also noticed that this looks related to *complex numbers* in one way or the other as it looks related to DeMoivers's law(*if we compare the real parts/imaginary parts differently*)-
$$(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))^n=\cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta)=e^{in\theta}$$
And also- 
$$\cos(n\theta)-i\sin(n\theta)=e^{-in\theta}$$ but I am not able to put all this together and relate it to the matrices $A,A^n$ also I have noticed $A^T×A=I$ but that doesn't help me much either.

---

Any help is appreciated

Comment: you can try induction method...Or if the matrix describes the rotation of a 2D vector with angle $\theta$, then $A^n$ would be $n$ rotations, hence the angle is $n\theta$.

Comment: @chip sorry but I couldn't understand what what you are talking about...can you please expand the comment ?

Comment: I assume you know how to use proof by induction (ie, show it works for $n=1$, assume same for $n$ and prove that implies same for $n+1$). Regarding 2D (two-dimensional) rotation, you can read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix or here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RotationMatrix.html.

Comment: Please look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/722342/raising-rotation-matrix-to-a-power). It might be of some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, there is a direct relation with DeMoivre.

Consider the complex numbers, regarded as a two-dimensional vector space $V$ over the real numbers, with basis $1, i$.

Consider the function $f : V \to V$ which maps
$$
z \mapsto z \cdot (\cos(\theta) + i \sin(\theta)).
$$
It is easy to see that this is a linear map. If you write the matrix of this map with respect to the basis $1, i$, you will find exactly your matrix $A$. More generally (to be used in a sec), the matrix associated to the map $z \mapsto z \cdot (a + i b)$ is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
   a & b\\
  -b & a\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Now $$f^{n} : z \mapsto z \cdot (\cos(\theta) + i \sin(\theta))^{n} = z \cdot (\cos(n \theta) + i \sin(n \theta))$$
by DeMoivre,
so the associated matrix will be
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
   \cos(n\theta) & \sin(n\theta)\\
  -\sin(n\theta) & \cos(n\theta)\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
But then you know that the matrix associated to $f^{n}$ is $A^{n}$. That's it!